# Map latitude and longitude differ for the same point in Openlayers compared to Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openlayers

I have a Leaflet with an indoor floor map populated with markers and Openlayers with the same map. 
While  I add markers to Openlayers with the same lat and long as Leaflet, the marker positions don't match.

Is any conversions necessary.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think providing an example with code of such a mismatch situation is necessary for people to understand your issue. The [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), and in particular about providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), provide some guidance.

Comment: probably good candidate for gis.stackexchange.com